# How to stop animationdrawable when mediaplayer finishes?

Tags: android, animation, media-player

I have a animation xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/anim"
    android:oneshot="true" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pik1"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pik2"
        android:duration="150"/>

</animation-list>
```

What i want to do is start and keep running the animation while mediaplayer is playing and stop the animation when mediaplaye is finished playing.

For Example: The mediaplayer is playing a sound which is 5 seconds long, i want to play the animation for 5 seconds an then stop is.

This is the jave code i have in my main activity:

```
piks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (play != null) {
                    play.reset();
                    play.release();
                }
                play = MediaPlayer.create(pikselActivity.this,
                        R.raw.pisound);
                play.start();
                frame.start();


            }
        });
```

frame.start() starts the animation, but when the sound is finished, the animation keeps running. How do i make the animation stop when the sound is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put an onCompletionListener()  on your media player. Inside the callback for media complete add

```
frame.clearAnimation();
```

like this:

```
if (play != null) {
    play.reset();
    play.release();
}
play = MediaPlayer.create(pikselActivity.this,R.raw.pisound);


play.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer mp){
        frame.clearAnimation();
    }
});
play.start();
frame.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement OnCompletionListener

```
play.setOnCompletionListener(new

OnCompletionListener() {

              @Override
              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                  frame.stop();


              }
          });
```